# How to kill the QRunnable in PyQt5?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qrunnable

I have an app with two buttons `start` and `end`. The start button will start a thread, which runs the audio recording function. This function is written using `sounddevice` and `soundfile` libraries. The audio recording can take place for an arbitary duration and the user can stop anytime by pressing `ctrl+c`.

So, now I want to implement a function for the `end` button to stop the thread which started by pressing `start` button or the function can send `ctrl+c` signal to the thread. So, that the current recording will be stopped. I am not sure how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

The code consisting in two *.py* is as it follows:

*audio_record.py*

```
import os
import signal
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import time
import queue
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import soundfile as sf
import sounddevice as sd
import mythreading


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 190, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_button_func)

        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 190, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.end_button_func)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "End"))

    def record(self):
        self.pid = os.getpid()
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        self.s = sd.InputStream(samplerate=48000, channels=2, callback=self.callback)
        try:
            # Make sure the file is open before recording begins
            with sf.SoundFile('check.wav', mode='x', samplerate=48000, channels=2, subtype="PCM_16") as file:
                with self.s:
                    # 1 second silence before the recording begins
                    time.sleep(1)
                    print('START')
                    print('#' * 80)
                    print('press Ctrl+C to stop the recording')
                    while True:
                        file.write(self.q.get())
        except OSError:
            print('The file to be recorded already exists.')
            sys.exit(1)

    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):

        """
        This function is called for each audio block from the record function.
        """

        if status:
            print(status, file=sys.stderr)
        self.q.put(indata.copy())

    def start_button_func(self):
        self.worker = mythreading.Worker(self.record)
        self.threadpool.start(self.worker)

    def end_button_func(self):
        print('how to stop?')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*mythreading.py* is as follows:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Worker(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.fn = fn

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.fn()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a flag, in this case `threading.Event()` to indicate that the thread should no longer be executed. For the case of `Ctrl + C` you must use `QShortcut`

```
import os
import queue
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import soundfile as sf
import sounddevice as sd
import mythreading
import threading

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 190, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 190, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "End"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadpool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_button_func)
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.end_button_func)
        self.event_stop = threading.Event()
        QtWidgets.QShortcut("Ctrl+C", self, activated=self.end_button_func)

    def record(self):
        self.pid = os.getpid()
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        self.s = sd.InputStream(samplerate=48000, channels=2, callback=self.callback)
        try:
            # Make sure the file is open before recording begins
            with sf.SoundFile('check.wav', mode='x', samplerate=48000, channels=2, subtype="PCM_16") as file:
                with self.s:
                    # 1 second silence before the recording begins
                    QtCore.QThread.sleep(1)
                    print('START')
                    print('#' * 80)
                    print('press Ctrl+C to stop the recording')
                    while not self.event_stop.is_set():
                        file.write(self.q.get())
                    print("STOP")
        except OSError:
            print('The file to be recorded already exists.')
            sys.exit(1)

    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        if status:
            print(status, file=sys.stderr)
        self.q.put(indata.copy())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start_button_func(self):
        print("start")
        self.worker = mythreading.Worker(self.record)
        self.threadpool.start(self.worker)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def end_button_func(self):
        print('how to stop?')
        self.event_stop.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllansec I have implemented in another way. But your idea works too. Thanks.

Comment: @eyllansec FYI, In your implementation the recording is not working if we have more than one file to be recorded. I have edited your code accordingly so that it will work.

Comment: @M.Denis Nowhere in your question do you indicate this requirement, so I have not modified your logic in that part. If you want to implement it the logic is that you delete that file if it exists before you burn a new one, or use a modified name like `some_name(1).wav`

Comment: @M.Denis Do not edit any answer if you are going to modify the logic, the modifications in your case must be in a non-substantive way, otherwise you are vandalizing in my answer.